# Excel Formula with Multiple Nested AND and OR Statements

Tags: excel, nested, arguments, formula

I'm using Excel formulas to perform some data audits. I currently am using the following to check the presence of values in certain columns:
`=IF(AND(I2<>"",T2="I",H3="n",OR(J2="",K2="",L2="",M2="",N2="",O2<1,P2="",Q2="",R2="",S2="")),"Error","Good")`

This works perfectly. But I need to add another condition to ignore the audit of Q2 when I2 = "BS". I attempted this with the following but it results in an error:   `=IF(AND(I2<>"",T2="I",H2="n",OR(J2="",K2="",L2="",M2="",N2="",O2<1,P2="",Q2="",R2="",S2="")),OR(AND(I2="00",T2="I",H2="n",OR(J2="",K2="",L2="",M2="",N2="",O2<1,P2="",R2="",S2="")),"Error","Good"))`

The goal is that if I2="BS" and the only cell missing data is Q2 the flag should be "Good" and not "Error". Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original (first) formula that you listed, replace `O2<1` with `AND(O2<1,I2<>"BS")`. What this does is that it tells the formula that there is only an error if `O2` is less than 1 **and** if `I2` *isn't* BS. Therefore, if `I2` is BS, `O2` will not cause an error (regardless of it's value).